# Vue binding data URI to img src property. Image in browser only updates when my OTHER props change somehow

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

I am generating a base64 string that represents an image and trying to pass that image data to a child component as the property of an object.

This is the class for my object that I want to pass to my child component. It has an image property as well as a few other properties. When my parent component changes otherData or id, things work fine. I will see the updated value in my child component. However, when image changes, I do not see the new image until I change a DIFFERENT property on my instance of MyDataModel! For example, if I change otherData, the new image suddenly appears on the screen. I am wondering if image is simply too big for Vue's change detection to handle. It's a base64 string to represent a 320x240 image, about 150KB in size.
Hower, if I take out image and declare it as a string property on my parent component...then the child component shows the updated image every time without fail.

```
export default class MyDataModel {
    public id!: string;
    public image!: string;
    public otherData: string;

    constructor(init?: Partial<MyDataModel>) {
        Object.assign(this, init);
    }
}
```

In my parent component, this is how I declare a new object representing the data for my child component

```
private childData = new MyDataModel();
```

In my parent component, this is how I create the image:

```
const data = this.$refs.cameraCanvas.toDataURL('image/png');
this.capturedImageData = data;
```

Then, I assin my image property to capturedImageData

```
this.childData.image = this.capturedImageData;
```

childData is a property of my child component

```
<ChildComponent :data="childData"></ChildComponent>
```

This is how I declare my data property in the child component

```
@Prop({required: true}) private data!: MyDataModel // MyDataModel is a typscript class with an image property
```

Lastly, this is how I am trying to show the image

```
<b-img id="input-image" :src="data.image"></b-img>
```

Answer (score 2):

Ah! The classic case of no re-render in child component on update... my old nemesis .
In these situations what you want to do is to... kind of *force* (or more accurately *coerce/trigger*) a re-render of the child component on the update. Here's the simplest (and most vue friendly) way to do that:

Add a property to your parent components' data

```js
/* ==== Parent component - script === */
data(){
  return {
  // ... other properties here 
  componentKey: 0, // this property - you can call it whatever, just let it be a number
  }
}
```

Bind that property to the child component

```js
/* ==== Parent component - template === */
<ChildComponent :data="childData" :key="componentKey"></ChildComponent>
```

Then, after assigning the capturedImageData, change the value of the property

```js
this.childData.image = this.capturedImageData;
this.componentKey += 1;
```

This should trigger a re-render of the child component, and the new image should be displayed.

Side note, you can also do this to emitted events from the child component to trigger a self-re-render like so

```js
<ChildComponent :data="childData" :key="componentKey" @someEmitEvent="componentKey += 1"></ChildComponent>
```

It's a bit hacky, but it works.

Comment: Your solution works! However, I gotta say, that's really silly. Is this a known bug in Vue?

Comment: @Genoe - It's not really a bug per se, just kind of how Vue's reactivity and rendering engine work. [This article](https://michaelnthiessen.com/key-changing-technique/)  and [this other article](https://michaelnthiessen.com/force-re-render/) go into further details if you're interested. Btw, if you don't mind, if it worked, could you kindly approve/upvote the answer? Thanks.